# run AlgoTrader Simulation in Eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse, error-handling, esper

I am trying to run the SimulationStarted class with the moving average strategy  in the open source edition of AlgoTrader.

When I start the SimulationStarter in eclipse I get

```
Exception in thread "main" com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceException: Error performing 'SimulationService.simulateWithCurrentParams()' --> com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceException: Error performing 'SimulationService.runByUnderlayings()' --> com.algoTrader.service.RuleServiceException: Error performing 'RuleService.initServiceProvider(String strategyName)' --> com.espertech.esper.client.EPException: esper-mov.cfg.xml not found
```

But it is running with the command java.exe -cp target/classes;../../AlgoTrader/code/target/classes;../../AlgoTrader/code/lib/*;target/* -Dsimulation=true -DdataSource.dataSet=1year com.algoTrader.starter.SimulationStarter simulateWithCurrentParams

If anyone knows how to fix it or any suggestions would be welcome. 
The whole exception output when I run the SimulationStarter in eclipse is:

```
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl initialized service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module market-data on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module current-values on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module trades on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module portfolio on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module performance on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module algo on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module ib-market-data on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module ib-trades on service provider: BASE 
Exception in thread "main" com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceException: Error performing 'SimulationService.simulateWithCurrentParams()' --> com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceException: Error performing 'SimulationService.runByUnderlayings()' --> com.algoTrader.service.RuleServiceException: Error performing 'RuleService.initServiceProvider(String strategyName)' --> com.espertech.esper.client.EPException: esper-mov.cfg.xml not found
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceBase.simulateWithCurrentParams(SimulationServiceBase.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.simulateWithCurrentParams(Unknown Source)
    at com.algoTrader.starter.SimulationStarter.main(SimulationStarter.java:29)
Caused by: com.espertech.esper.client.EPException: esper-mov.cfg.xml not found
    at com.espertech.esper.client.Configuration.getResourceAsStream(Configuration.java:928)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:784)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:767)
    at com.algoTrader.service.RuleServiceImpl.handleInitServiceProvider(RuleServiceImpl.java:81)
    at com.algoTrader.service.RuleServiceBase.initServiceProvider(RuleServiceBase.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.initServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceImpl.handleRunByUnderlayings(SimulationServiceImpl.java:139)
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceBase.runByUnderlayings(SimulationServiceBase.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.runByUnderlayings(Unknown Source)
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceImpl.handleSimulateWithCurrentParams(SimulationServiceImpl.java:183)
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceBase.simulateWithCurrentParams(SimulationServiceBase.java:242)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to run SimulationStarter inside the project algotrader-code. However to run the simulation you need to run it inside the algotrader-mov project

P.S. for more information: [Run the AlgoTrader in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478252/run-the-algotrader-in-eclipse)