# Run the AlgoTrader in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, open-source

I am trying to run the AlgoTrader in Eclipse but I get two errors

The only problem now is when I run the SimulationStarter class I get the following error:

```
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl initialized service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module market-data on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module current-values on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module trades on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module portfolio on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module performance on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module algo on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module ib-market-data on service provider: BASE 
1989-12-31 23:00:00,000 DEBUG RuleServiceImpl deployed module ib-trades on service provider: BASE 
Exception in thread "main" com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceException: Error performing 'SimulationService.simulateWithCurrentParams()' --> com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceException: Error performing 'SimulationService.runByUnderlayings()' --> com.algoTrader.service.RuleServiceException: Error performing 'RuleService.initServiceProvider(String strategyName)' --> com.espertech.esper.client.EPException: esper-mov.cfg.xml not found
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceBase.simulateWithCurrentParams(SimulationServiceBase.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.simulateWithCurrentParams(Unknown Source)
    at com.algoTrader.starter.SimulationStarter.main(SimulationStarter.java:29)
Caused by: com.espertech.esper.client.EPException: esper-mov.cfg.xml not found
    at com.espertech.esper.client.Configuration.getResourceAsStream(Configuration.java:928)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:784)
    at com.espertech.esper.client.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:767)
    at com.algoTrader.service.RuleServiceImpl.handleInitServiceProvider(RuleServiceImpl.java:81)
    at com.algoTrader.service.RuleServiceBase.initServiceProvider(RuleServiceBase.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.initServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceImpl.handleRunByUnderlayings(SimulationServiceImpl.java:139)
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceBase.runByUnderlayings(SimulationServiceBase.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor.invoke(HibernateInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.runByUnderlayings(Unknown Source)
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceImpl.handleSimulateWithCurrentParams(SimulationServiceImpl.java:183)
    at com.algoTrader.service.SimulationServiceBase.simulateWithCurrentParams(SimulationServiceBase.java:242)
    ... 14 more
```

[image]

I am able to run the `MOV strategy` in the cmd but I have been stuck here for a very long time!

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions they would be much appreciated as this is very important for me and I have tried everything I could think of.

Comment: I have had the same problem with eclipse and could not resolve it. I think you can run the open source version only in the comand prompt and you need the enterprice version in order to run it in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem you can solve it when you add the  after the build.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>  

    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The second one seems quite complex. Everyone that can solve it is machine

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to run SimulationStarter inside the project `algotrader-code`. However to run the simulation you need to run it inside the `algotrader-mov` project

[image: SimulationStarter]
<sub>(source: [algotrader.ch](http://www.algotrader.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/SimulationStarter.gif))</sub>

Hope this helps!